# paramiko Authentication rejected with error 877

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I'm using paramiko in python to run command through ssh. I used the following code:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('MY-SERVER-IP', username='USERNAME',password='PASSWORD')
stdin, stdout, stderr =  ssh.exec_command("uptime")
print stdout.readlines()
```

There isn't any problem with typical Linux hosts, but when trying that on a special Linux box ( the box has a customized shell of Ubuntu 12.04), this error appears:

> Authentication rejected with error : 877

What's the problem? I can connect to my special Linux box by traditional ssh clients such as Linux ssh-client and putty.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe related to https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/67 or https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/88 ?

Comment: These issues are about the host key which occurs before username request from the server (I've solved this problem with the third line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. The problem is due to `exec_command` function. It doesn't request **pseudo-terminal** from the server so my box cannot handle a non-interactive shell without pseudo-terminal request. To overcome this issue, I used `get_pty=True` argument in calling `exec_command`, so the fourth line replace with:

```
ssh.connect('MY-SERVER-IP', username='USERNAME',password='PASSWORD',get_pty=True)
```